# Send message to dms discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, discord, discord.py

I want to send message to dms using my discord bot and because the api has changed from `client.send_message(user, message)` to `channel.send(message)` I have no idea how to do that, also I dont want to make it dependent on the `on_message(message)` event. Any ideas?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-dm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the user ID you can do:

```
user = client.get_user(user_id)
await user.send('Hello')
```

However If you already have the User object, you can do the following:

```
await message.author.send('Hey')
```

Where message is a Message object received from a `on_message()` event.

As for whether you can send private messages without first receiving an event unfortunately that is not be possible due to obvious spam-related issues.